# Show QCalendarWidget for Shamsi (Jalali) in Python and pyqt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I want to know QCalendarWidget(pyqt and in python) for Persian displayed What should I do?
Or any other language except the English(for example Persian, Arabic,Russian, etc)
Thanks

Comment: Do you have any code you tried?...Plus, you need to use Persian and Arabic encoding to display them properly

Comment: I do not mean that in displaying Persian texts have problems.  
For example, instead of showing the month of July, equivalent in Persian displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the language display in `QCalenderWidget` by changing the language in `local` properties to `Persian` using `Qt`

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

**EDIT:**

If you want to have calendars with Jalali and Hijri support, and persian translation, then you will have to install [StarCalender](https://www.openhub.net/p/starcal) package and use its library for such thing.

Here its source fourge [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/starcal/?source=typ_redirect) as well

Comment: yes it worked, But still in the header month and year for the Gregorian was shown

Comment: If you are considering in the header Writing دسامبر 2015.but i want to write آذر 1394.

Comment: آذر is a jalali month

Comment: Then, you will have to use the `starcal` package, https://www.openhub.net/p/starcal

Answer (score 2):

## Short Answer

You can't. (Yet)

## Long answer

[Qt does not support calendars](http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/development/2016-December/028125.html). There is a [work-in-progress](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-58404) (code available [here](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/182341/)) to add non-Gregorian calendaring support for Qt in QtWidgets and QtQuick modules. If everything goes fine, the patch will be merged into Qt 5.11. It's stable enough for now, so you can apply it to Qt 5.10 source and you should be fine.

**Disclaimer**: I'm not aware of possible licensing issues (if you made changes to Qt, you may need to publish your source code[?]).

**Important Notes:**

Calendars and Locale are separated and unrelated concepts. This animated gif should elaborate more (it's an early test of our proposed change to Qt):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
cal = QtGui.QCalendarWidget()
cal.setLocale(QtCore.QLocale.Persian)
```

Comment: TypeError: QWidget.setLocale(QLocale): argument 1 has unexpected type 'Language'

Comment: Excuse me a question:
How do I set Friday as a holiday week

Comment: I am sorry to say this but please consider to give some effort from your side too http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlocale.html there you have all the info you want

Comment: This will only change the Locale, not the Calendar.